# PHP PDO - commit to database even there is an error

Tags: php, pdo

I have a tag system designed like this:

### tag

```
CREATE TABLE `tag` (
  `tag_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `user_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `add_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`tag_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=0;
```

### user

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `user_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=0;
```

`tag.user_is` is a foreign key, every user can create new tag(s) if it's new(no user have been created before). My problem here with PDO commit method, it stops at the first existence of row and return this error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'restaurant' for key 'name'
```

So, is there a way to tell PDO engine to continue commit even there is error?

```
<?php
  $db->beginTransaction();

  for ($i = 0; $i < count($tags); ++$i)
  {
    $db->execute('INSERT INTO tag(name, user_id) VALUES('.$db->quote($tags[$i]).','.$user_id.')')
  }

  $db->commit();

?>
```

Comment: Why not write your query as a `replace into`, `insert ... on duplicate key update`, or something like that instead of `insert` if you need to maintain a unique constraint on the `name` field?  I think just ignoring your error is generally not a good idea.

Comment: transactions are made for error tracking and being able to rollback.
If you don't care about errors, why do you use transactions in the first place?

Comment: @MikeBrant You comment is the answer and solution I was looking for, would you re-post it as answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @Loïc To win performance.

Comment: @HAßdøµ then use multiple inserts, check this : http://www.electrictoolbox.com/mysql-insert-multiple-records/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not write your query as a `replace into`, `insert ... on duplicate key update`, or something like that instead of `insert` if you need to maintain a unique constraint on the `name` field? I think just ignoring your error is generally not a good idea.